# User input string variable in C

Tags: c, user-input

So I am learning the C programming language and I want to run a basic script in which the user inputs a variable and the variable that is printed out is the one in which the user inputed, which is simple, however, the code I wrote prints a random thing that has nothing to do with the code, please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char main(void){
        char var[3];
        printf("Enter your name: ");
        scanf("%1f", &var);
        printf("%s", &var);

        }
```

Comment: Why are you allocating three characters? And what do you think `&var` means? And what do you think `%1f` does? It's hard to explain what you did wrong without understanding why you thought what you did was right.

Comment: main should have a return value of either int or void

Comment: try `char name[64]; scanf("%63s", name); printf("%s\n", name);`

Comment: `scanf("%1f", &var);`   I am not a number. I am a free man!

Comment: `scanf("%1f", &var);
        printf("%s", &var);` --> `scanf("%2s", var);  printf("%s\n", var);`  (Useful for names shorter than 3 characters like the first name `"J."`.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many ways you can answer your question. First off, let's do it the way your example does it. Explanation of each line will be on the side.

> Example 1:

```
#include <stdio.h> //You are require this header to do the basic C stuff

void main(void){ //Main loop to run your code
        char var[3]; //An array to store data
        printf("Enter your name: ");
        scanf("%s", &var); //I removed 1f because you don't require 1 and f is float only 
        printf("%s", &var);

        }
```

> Example 2:

```
#include <stdio.h> //You are require this header to do the basic C stuff

main(){ // Main loop to run your code
        char var; //An char var to store data
        printf("Enter your name: ");
        scanf("%c", &var); 
        printf("%c", &var);

        }
```

Comment: You compile it with `-Wall` (or `/Wall` or such as) option. and execute it then See result.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void){
    char var[20];
    printf("Enter your name: \n");
    scanf("%s", var);  // Note: %s is for char arrays and not %f(floats)
    printf("%s", var);  // Note: no ampersand here

}
```